# Sort List by two different Lists

Tags: c#

I am trying to sort some data by category. Each category has a count, or the number of entries in the category and a score which I have given the category. The score is the most important and should always be considered first when sorting. The count is not as important as the score, but is still important and should be considered second when sorting.

```
List<string> categories = new List<string>();
List<int> count = new List<int>();
List<int> score = new List<int>();

categories.Add("category1");
count.Add(23);
score.Add(8);
...
for(int i = 0; i < sortedcategories.Count; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(sortedCategories[i] + sortedScore[i] + sortedCount[i]);
}
// Should Output
/*
category8 [Score: 10] [Count: 8]
category2 [Score: 10] [Count: 5]
category1 [Score: 8] [Count: 23]
category5 [Score: 7] [Count: 12]
category4 [Score: 5] [Count: 28]
category3 [Score: 5] [Count: 25]
category7 [Score: 5] [Count: 17]
category6 [Score: 2] [Count: 34]
*/
```

How can I perform a sorting operation that will give me the output above?
(If this is easier to to with arrays I can use arrays too)

Comment: Right now you have 3 independent lists... seems messy. Why not create a class containing 3 properties and create a list of that class?

Comment: Because I didn't think of, or know how to do/sort that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3 independent lists aren't recommended. Create a Class to store your categories

```
public class Category 
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public int Score { get; set; }
     public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then fill your list with categories

```
// In your method add a category to list
var categories = new List<Category>();
categories.Add(new Category {
     Name = "Category1",
     Score = 10,
     Count = 3
});
```

Sort your categories using System.Linq

```
var sortedCategores = categories.OrderByDescending(x => x.Score).ThenByDescending(x => x.Count).ToList();
```

Iterate through your collection

```
foreach(var category in sortedCategores)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{category.Name} [Score: {category.Score}] [Count: {category.Count}]");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to create a class that holds the associated properties from each list instead of trying to manage a bunch of lists and the order of their items. We can also [override the `ToString` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-override-the-tostring-method) of this class so it outputs the formatted string that you're currently using by default:

```
class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} [Score: {Score}] [Count: {Count}]";
    }
}
```

Then you can create a single list of this type instead of three different lists. Here's a sample that uses your existing lists to populate a new list, but ideally you'd modify your code that adds items to the three lists to instead add a new `Category` to the single list. Once you have this single list, you can order it by any property (and then by any other property) that you like by using the `System.Linq` extension methods, [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.7.2) (which puts the smallest items first) or [`OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending?view=netframework-4.7.2) (which puts the largest items first):

```
var items = new List<Category>();

// Create a list of items based off your three lists
// (this assumes that all three lists have the same count).
// Ideally, the list of Items would be built instead of the three other lists
for (int i = 0; i < categories.Count; i++)
{
    items.Add(new Category
    {
        Name = categories[i],
        Count = count[i],
        Score = score[i]
    });
}

// Now you can sort by any property, and then by any other property
// OrderBy will put smallest first, OrderByDescending will put largest first
items = items.OrderByDescending(item => item.Score)
    .ThenByDescending(item => item.Count)
    .ToList();

// Write each item to the console
items.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
```

**Output**

[image: ![enter image description here]